# How to properly reorder the raster data from bottom up to top down?

Tags: gdal, gdal.net

When creating a raster I set the lower-left x/y values, and asc file has the following "header":

```
ncols        1731
nrows        1863
xllcorner    17548488.944545675069
yllcorner    -8069349.376163828187
dx           500.162987955558
dy           500.081943659035
```

Note that the raster data is going from bottom to top.

However, now it seems that I need to reorder the raster data so that my raster data will appear from top to bottom, instead of bottom to top. In the above case, I want the `dy` to assume negative value.

Is there any built-in function for this?

I could have reorder it manually:

```
   using (var ds = Gdal.Open(demInputTiff, Access.GA_Update))
    {
        var nCol = ds.RasterXSize;
        var nRow = ds.RasterYSize;
        double[] geoTransform = new double[6];
        ds.GetGeoTransform(geoTransform);

        if (geoTransform[5] < 0)
            return; //no need transformation 

        geoTransform[3] += geoTransform[5] * (nRow -1);
        geoTransform[5] *= -1;

        ds.SetGeoTransform(geoTransform);

        Band band = ds.GetRasterBand(1);
        var allValues = new int[nCol * nRow];
        var noData = band.NoDataValue();
        band.ReadRaster(0, 0, nCol, nRow, allValues, nCol, nRow, 0, 0);

        //manual reordering, crude way of iterating through the array
        var allValues2 = new int[nCol * nRow];
        for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++)
            {
                allValues2[(nRow - i - 1) * nCol + j] = allValues[i * nCol + j];
            }
        }

        band.WriteRaster(0, 0, nCol, nRow, allValues2, nCol, nRow, 0, 0);


        ds.FlushCache();
    }
```

But I'm pretty sure that this is not the most efficient way of doing things, both memory and speed wise. There is also an issue of whether .Net array can hold that big the array size or not.

Is there a built-in function for this?

Comment: If GDAL reads it properly (no reason it shouldn't) translate (with GDAL_Translate utility) to GeoTIFF (GTIFF) or imagine (HFA) format then translate to AAIGRID and the pixel ordering should be top-down.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, is the performance/memory better in that case?

Comment: @MichaelStimson is there any guarantee that such translation to AAIGRID will always result in top down pixel ? Guarantee as in the sense that this behavior is explicitly documented and unlikely to change

Comment: You can read the code in the driver https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/frmts/aaigrid/aaigriddataset.cpp and see how it is implemented, anecdotally AAIGRID files are written top down but I don't know for sure whether it's a copy of the existing orientation or an assertion of *top down* georeference; You might be able to convert directly from asc to asc but proceeding via a GeoTIFF or HFA should rectify the *bottom up* georeference, HFA being safer as TIFF files can have an orientation other than top-left addressing.